# php rows in mysql as column

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I use codeigniter as framework. I want to make a table (in view file), which will show the exams as columns, and the students grades as rows.

First i made two tables in mysql:
- one for the exams 
- one for the grades

My table in mysql for the exams is as follow:

```
table_exams
exams_id | title       | class_id
---------+-------------+---------
1        | mathematics | 5
2        | biology     | 5
3        | gymnastic   | 5
4        | pyhsics     | 3
```

and the second table in mysql for the grades is as follow:

```
table_grades
grades_id | exams_id | student_name | grade
----------+----------+--------------+------
1         | 1        | Jackson      | 5
2         | 1        | Lisa         | 4
3         | 2        | jackson      | 2
4         | 2        | Lisa         | 4
5         | 3        | Lisa         | 1
```

---

In php view file I want to get this:

if i want to see the exams for class 5

First column is the student name.
the other columns are the exams (from mysql exams table).
For each student in that class i want to get a row with the grades (getting from mysql table grades) like this:

```
studentname | mathematics | biology | gymnastic
------------+-------------+---------+---------------
Jackson     | 5           | 2       | no exams made
Lisa        | 4           | 4       | 1
```

---

i tried the following code for the headers

```
<th><?php echo get_phrase('student');?></th>
$this->db->where('class_id', 5);
$exams = $this->db->get('student_tb_exams')->result_array();
foreach($exams as $row):?>
    echo $row['title']; 
endforeach;
```

and for the table body

```
<tr>
<?php                   
    $this->db->select('*'); 
    $this->db->from('student_tb_grades');
    $this->db->join('student_tb_exams','student_tb_grades.exams_id = student_tb_exams.exams_id','INNER'); 
    $this->db->where('class_id', 5);
    $grades = $this->db->get()->result_array();
    foreach($grades as $row):?>
        <td><?php echo $row['student_id'];?></td>
        <?php echo $row['grade'];?></td>
    endforeach;
```

but i get:

```
studentname | mathematics | biology | gymnastic     |
------------+-------------+---------+---------------
Jackson     | 5           |         |               |
Lisa        | 4           |         |               |
Jackson     | 2           |         |               |
Lisa        | 4           |         |               |
Jackson     |             |         |               |
Lisa        | 1           |         |               |
```

How can i get one row for each student and the grades in the right column? So grade for math in the mathematics column, grade for biology in the biology column.

Comment: This has been answered here already
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21548789/codeigniter-active-record-for-joining-the-tables/28326364#28326364][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21548789/codeigniter-active-record-for-joining-the-tables/28326364#28326364

Comment: i looked at that topic, but isnot the same

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in your SQL : $this->db->where('class_id', 5);
Why you don't JOIN in exams_id for get each user all exams after you just need get grade for exams and user.
And for get juste 2 row Jackson and Lisa you need to make GROUPE BY in you sql on student_name

Comment: if i use groupe_by i will get one row for Jackson and one row for Lisa, but it will only set the grade under column mathematics, the other columns will be empty